# Disable Windows and Alt-Tab Key Combo(s)

Tags: windows-7

I'm just looking for a program which can disable the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on a keyboard and also the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut, but leave other shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> for start menu, etc) still active.

Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 3):

To disable Alt-Tab edit the following registry key, and then reboot:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"CoolSwitch"="0"
```

Regarding the Windows keys, there is a [page with some other .reg files here](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_windows_key/), but I have not tried them.

Good luck!